# Topology manager error

Tags: web8

we are getting foloowing error in Event log viewer after clicking on Experience Manager button in site.

```
Cannot get publish source for the URL 'http://www.site.com'. Exception occured in the TopologyManager 'http://localhost:81/ttm201501'. Mapping for the specified CmEnvironmentId 'ProdTridioncm01_54408111' and url 'http://www.site.com' could not be found.
Exception occured in the TopologyManager 'http://localhost:81/ttm201501'. Mapping for the specified CmEnvironmentId 'ProdTridioncm01_54408111' and url 'http://www.site.com' could not be found.
An error occurred while processing this request.
{"error":{"code":"IdNotFound","message":"Mapping for the specified CmEnvironmentId 'ProdTridioncm01_54408111' and url 'http://www.site.com' could not be found.","lang":"en-US","exceptionDetails":{"typeName":"TopologyManagerException","stackTrace":"   at Tridion.TopologyManager.Mapping.GetByUrl(String cmEnvironmentId, Uri uri)\r\n   at Tridion.TopologyManager.Service.Controllers.MappingsController.GetMappingByUrl(String queryUrl)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"}}}
  Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 781 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.InnerSynchExecute[TElement](Uri requestUri, String httpMethod, Nullable`1 singleResult, OperationParameter[] operationParameters)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute[TElement](Uri requestUri)
   at Tridion.TopologyManager.Client.TopologyManagerClient.GetMappingByUrl(Uri fullUri, String cmEnvironmentId)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CmTopologyManagerClient.GetMappingByUrl(Uri fullUri, String cmEnvironmentId)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CmTopologyManagerClient.GetMappingByUrl(Uri fullUri, String cmEnvironmentId)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.SystemManager.GetPublishSourceByUrl(Uri url)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.SystemManager.GetPublishSourceByUrl(Uri url)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.GetPublishSourceByUrl(String url)
   at SyncInvokeGetPublishSourceByUrl(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

we have disabled Topology Manager in our environment and we didnt get any mapping id while executing below query in power shell.
[image]

we are using cd_preview_webservice in linux machine and we are using old publishing model.
Could you please let us know if anything should we disable ?
Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, XPM tries to use the Core Service method `GetPublishSourceByUrl`, which only works if Topology Manager is used.

If all is well, XPM should fall back to using legacy App Data on Publication Targets if Topology Manager is not used.

Does XPM work properly despite this error in the event log? If so, the error can be ignored (see above). If not, please contact SDL Support for further analysis

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for your answer. XPM working perfectly.